# convert list of tuples to lists of dicts with whole tuples as keys

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a nested list of tuples as given below,

```
>>> my_nested_list_of_tuples
  [[('AU041133(+)', 'Qtrt1'), ('Ahr(+)', 'Mex3c'), ('Arid3a(+)', 'Hmgb1')],     
  [('AU041133(+)', 'Topors'), ('Ahr(+)', 'Mex3c'), ('Arid3a(+)', 'Hmgb1')],   
  [('AU041133(+)', 'Tm9sf3'), ('Ahr(+)', 'Mex3c'), ('Arid3a(+)', 'Hmgb1')], 
  [('AU041133(+)', 'Gsn'), ('Ahr(+)', 'Ireb2'), ('Arid3a(+)', 'Hmgb1')],
  [('AU041133(+)', 'Tm9sf3'), ('Ahr(+)', 'Ilf3'), ('Arid3a(+)', 'Arid3a')]]
```

I want to convert the above nested list of tuples to list of dictionaries with whole tuple as key and 0 as value as given below

```
 [{('AU041133(+)', 'Qtrt1'): 0, ('Ahr(+)', 'Mex3c'): 0, ('Arid3a(+)', 'Hmgb1'): 0},
 {('AU041133(+)', 'Topors'): 0, ('Ahr(+)', 'Mex3c'): 0, ('Arid3a(+)', 'Hmgb1'): 0},  
 {('AU041133(+)', 'Tm9sf3'): 0, ('Ahr(+)', 'Mex3c'): 0, ('Arid3a(+)', 'Hmgb1'): 0}, 
 {('AU041133(+)', 'Gsn'): 0, ('Ahr(+)', 'Ireb2'): 0, ('Arid3a(+)', 'Hmgb1'): 0}, 
 {('AU041133(+)', 'Tm9sf3'): 0, ('Ahr(+)', 'Ilf3'): 0, ('Arid3a(+)', 'Arid3a'): 0}]
```

I have tried various methods for achieving this but I am not successful in doing so, one of the way I tried is given below,

```
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> dk=[] # for populating with list of dicts
>>> for k in my_tops: 
...     for i,v in k:
...          d[(i,v)].append(0)
...     dk.append(d)
... 

>>> dk
[defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {('AU041133(+)', 'Qtrt1'): [0], ('Ahr(+)', 'Mex3c'):  [0, 0, 0], 
('Arid3a(+)', 'Hmgb1'): [0, 0, 0, 0], ('AU041133(+)', 'Topors'): [0], ('AU041133(+)', 'Tm9sf3'): [0, 0], 
('AU041133(+)', 'Gsn'): [0], ('Ahr(+)', 'Ireb2'): [0], ('Ahr(+)', 'Ilf3'): [0], ('Arid3a(+)', 'Arid3a'): [0]}), 
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {('AU041133(+)', 'Qtrt1'): [0], ('Ahr(+)', 'Mex3c'): [0, 0, 0], 
('Arid3a(+)', 'Hmgb1'): [0, 0, 0, 0], ('AU041133(+)', 'Topors'): [0],  ('AU041133(+)', 'Tm9sf3'): [0, 0], 
('AU041133(+)', 'Gsn'): [0], ('Ahr(+)', 'Ireb2'): [0], ('Ahr(+)', 'Ilf3'): [0],  ('Arid3a(+)', 'Arid3a'): [0]}), 
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {('AU041133(+)', 'Qtrt1'): [0], ('Ahr(+)', 'Mex3c'): [0, 0, 0], 
('Arid3a(+)', 'Hmgb1'): [0, 0, 0, 0], ('AU041133(+)', 'Topors'): [0], ('AU041133(+)', 'Tm9sf3'): [0, 0], 
('AU041133(+)', 'Gsn'): [0], ('Ahr(+)', 'Ireb2'): [0], ('Ahr(+)', 'Ilf3'): [0], ('Arid3a(+)', 'Arid3a'): [0]}), 
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {('AU041133(+)', 'Qtrt1'): [0], ('Ahr(+)', 'Mex3c'): [0, 0, 0], 
 ('Arid3a(+)', 'Hmgb1'): [0, 0, 0, 0], ('AU041133(+)', 'Topors'): [0], ('AU041133(+)', 'Tm9sf3'): [0, 0], 
('AU041133(+)', 'Gsn'): [0], ('Ahr(+)', 'Ireb2'): [0], ('Ahr(+)', 'Ilf3'): [0], ('Arid3a(+)', 'Arid3a'): [0]}), 
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {('AU041133(+)', 'Qtrt1'): [0], ('Ahr(+)', 'Mex3c'): [0, 0, 0], ('Arid3a(+)', 'Hmgb1'): [0, 0, 0, 0], 
('AU041133(+)', 'Topors'): [0], ('AU041133(+)', 'Tm9sf3'): [0, 0], 
('AU041133(+)', 'Gsn'): [0], ('Ahr(+)', 'Ireb2'): [0], ('Ahr(+)', 'Ilf3'): [0],  ('Arid3a(+)', 'Arid3a'): [0]})]
```

Is there a way to get the expected output as given in the second chunk of code?

Thanks,

Comment: `[{k:0 for k in item} for item in my_nested_list_of_tuples]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly your question, the solution could be:

```py
dict_list=[]
>>> for row in my_nested_list_of_tuples:
...     dict_list.append({key:0 for key in row})

[{('AU041133(+)', 'Qtrt1'): 0, ('Ahr(+)', 'Mex3c'): 0, ('Arid3a(+)', 'Hmgb1'): 0},
 {('AU041133(+)', 'Topors'): 0, ('Ahr(+)', 'Mex3c'): 0, ('Arid3a(+)', 'Hmgb1'): 0},
 {('AU041133(+)', 'Tm9sf3'): 0, ('Ahr(+)', 'Mex3c'): 0, ('Arid3a(+)', 'Hmgb1'): 0},
 {('AU041133(+)', 'Gsn'): 0, ('Ahr(+)', 'Ireb2'): 0, ('Arid3a(+)', 'Hmgb1'): 0},
 {('AU041133(+)', 'Tm9sf3'): 0, ('Ahr(+)', 'Ilf3'): 0, ('Arid3a(+)', 'Arid3a'): 0}]
```